# How to make this function not return a negative date diffence?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The function is trying to fund the difference between to dates, but I am struggling to not return a negative number if the date is past a certain point. I have tried a few work around like using ABS but it can cause problems in future areas.

```js
var DateCalc = {};

DateCalc.totalDaysLeft = 0;

DateCalc.calculate = function(dateToParse) {
  DateCalc.init(dateToParse);
  return DateCalc.stringify(DateCalc.years(), DateCalc.months(), DateCalc.days());
};

DateCalc.init = function(dateToParse) {
  var date = DateCalc.parseDate(dateToParse);
  var today = Date.now();
  var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  DateCalc.totalDaysLeft = Math.floor((date - today) / oneDay);
};

DateCalc.parseDate = function(dateToParse) {
  var dateVars = dateToParse.split(',').map(Number);
  return new Date(dateVars[0], dateVars[1] - 1, dateVars[2]);
};

DateCalc.years = function() {
  var years = Math.floor(DateCalc.totalDaysLeft / 365);
  DateCalc.totalDaysLeft -= Math.floor(years * 365);
  return years;
};

DateCalc.months = function() {
  var months = Math.floor(DateCalc.totalDaysLeft / 30);
  DateCalc.totalDaysLeft -= Math.floor(months * 30);
  return months;
};

DateCalc.days = function() {
  return Math.floor(DateCalc.totalDaysLeft / 24);
};

DateCalc.stringify = function(years, months, days) {
  var dateString = "";

  if (years !== 0)
    dateString += years + " years, ";
  if (months !== 0)
    dateString += months + " months, ";
  dateString += days + " day(s).";

  return dateString;
};

//here is the .abs() code. 


function age(year, month, day) {
  var yearDifference = Math.abs(new Date().getFullYear() - year);
  var monthDifference = Math.abs(new Date().getMonth() - month + 1);
  var dayDifference = Math.abs(new Date().getDate() - day);

  var differences = {
    year: yearDifference,
    month: monthDifference,
    day: dayDifference
  };
  var final = [];

  for (var time in differences) {
    if (differences[time] > 0) {
      var addString = differences[time] + " " + time;
      if (differences[time] > 1) {
        addString += "s"
      }
      final.push(addString);
    }
  }
  return final.join(" ");
};
console.log(age(2017, 11, 17));
console.log(age(2016, 1, 2));
```

//if you tried to look up how far away next January is while you're in December, it will tell you it is 1 year 11 months from now instead of 1 month. This is because it adds the 11 months instead of subtracting it.I am trying to find a solution, as this function is more conscise but the other is more versatile. The function above, I replaced .floor() with rounds the value down with .abs() hoping it would just use the absolute value of the given operation, however, this was not the case.

Comment: use `Math.abs(num)` to get the absolute value

Comment: Can you please post a few examples of the expected output?

Comment: I have tried using Math.abs(num) however  I was told "The absolute value method has errors that become more prominent as the year goes on. For instance, if you tried to look up how far away next January is while you're in December, it will tell you it is 1 year 11 months from now instead of 1 month. This is because it adds the 11 months instead of subtracting it. You can actually see this error in work right now by trying to get the amount of time until last December."

Comment: @Amnon absolutely Here is an example DateCalc(2015, 3, 6) -> 4 day 
(2017, 11, 17) -> 2 years, 8 months, 15 days

Comment: Let me know if you need any more info. @Amnon

Comment: @thecommunictycodeguy - you're using it wrong then

Comment: Obviously there can be cases where the result is negative, so what do you mean by "not return a negative number"? What should be returned instead? Secondly, I can only warn you against trying to implement your own date calculations. Such calculations are exceptionally complex, and there are good reasons for the large libraries which exist for such calculations. For example, your code does not take leap years into account, let alone leap seconds, time zones and so on.

Comment: @Binarus I absolutely agree with that, this is strictly an exercise and I understand using the standard library is much more beneficial when writing something to be implemented commercially etc.  Here is an example of the issue I am having: When using `.abs()` it causes the calculations to be thrown off. The desired output is if calculating the dates between (2015,2,13) and todays date  2 years, 12 months, 0 day(s)  not -2 years, 12 months, 0 day(s) which is what I am currently getting.

Comment: I think I now have understood what you would like to do. But I did not see how and where exactly you are using .abs(). Could you please provide your complete code (the version that uses .abs()) so that we eventually can reproduce the problem and suggest a solution?

Comment: Absolutely, do you want me to link to a JSfiddle or just paste it here? @Binarus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the .abs() function in an inappropriate way. Most mathematical functions do no obey the distributive rule, and the .abs() function belongs to these. For an easier understanding, let us forget your current problem for a moment and let us examine a simple, reduced example:

Let's say you want to know the absolute value of -10. Obviously, the correct result is +10.

On the other hand, -10 could be written as (-20 + 10). But nevertheless, you can *not* compute abs(-10) using that knowledge:

abs(-20 + 10) = 10, but
abs(-20) + abs(+10) = 30

Applying that knowledge to your problem, we see that abs(Y years + M months + D days) is generally NOT equal to (abs(Y years) + abs(M months) + abs(D days)).

Regarding this problem, there is the additional oddity that each of the terms of the result has another unit, and that the terms depend on each other (e.g. there can be no term like "13 months", because that would be "1 year plus 1 month"), but I won't go into further detail here.

**There is a simple solution:**

1) Determine the desired resolution of your result (i.e. should your result be accurate to seconds, attoseconds, days or something else).

2) Convert the two dates into the unit determined in step 1), using a randomly chosen, yet fixed point in time as the common starting point.

3) Now you can subtract the two (converted) dates and use the .abs() function without problems.

4) Convert the result back into human readable form.

How do you do that in practice? Well, steps 1), 3) and 4) are easy, but what about step 2)?

Nearly every OS I know (and thus, nearly every programming language) does the conversion needed in step 2) for you. More often than not, the fixed point in time is 1970-01-01 00:00:00, and the OS / programming language provides routines to convert any date / time to the number of seconds (or some other unit) which have elapsed since this fixed point.

For example, in JavaScript, the myDate.getTime() function returns the number of *milliseconds* which have passed since 1970-01-01 up to myDate.

So convert both dates to "milliseconds since 1970-01-01" and subtract them. Use the .abs() function on the result. Then you have the desired time span as a value of positive milliseconds. Convert that back to human readable form, i.e. years, months and days (which is no problem, is it?)

**A second simple solution (just for avoiding negative results):**

I hope that you agree with me that *comparing* two dates is much easier than computing the difference between them (first compare the year; if the years differ, you have undoubtedly found the "greater" date; if the years are equal, do the same with the months, and so on). Then exchange the two dates if necessary. That way, you always can make sure that you subtract the "smaller" date from the "greater" date and that the result always will be positive.

But please note that even when doing so there will still be negative results in parts of the calculation when actually subtracting the dates, so you would have exactly the same problems when using the .abs() function.

**A more complicated solution:**

You could do the subtraction yourself as well, but then the .abs() function won't help you much. One of the algorithms I can think of could work like a subtraction which is done by hand (I mean the subtraction of normal numbers you have learned in school):

Begin with the least significant unit (for example the days). Subtract the days; if the result is negative, then add 28, 29, 30 or 31 (depending on the month) and make a carry to the months, otherwise keep the result; then do the same thing with the months, and so on. But as I already wrote in my comment, there are many pitfalls when doing so (leap years, months have different numbers of days, and so on), and the .abs() function will not help you here.

**Conclusion:**

Personally, I would prefer the first (simple) solution I have given. It is easy, understandable and future-proof.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. The simpler solution is exactly what I went for and I was able to rewrite it and get the desired result. Thanks for the excellent feedback @Binarus, you should teach a class.

Comment: Never mind. If it helped, it would be nice if you could mark my answer as accepted answer ... And keep going on - trying the very basic things and (just for exercise, not for production) using own function instead of libraries will make you gain a deep understanding for what happens behind the scenes when using libraries.

Comment: I only have 14 reputation at the moment, as soon as I reach 15 I will up vote your answer. Thanks for the tip and I hope that my such is the case so my understanding will become deeper. Thank goodness for all those awesome libraries out there right?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//initial variables

var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
var year = today.getFullYear();
var otherDate = new Date();
var day2 = 0;
var month2 = 0;
var year2 = 0;



if (day < 10) {
  day = '0' + day;
}

if (month < 10) {
  month = '0' + month;
}

function age(day2, month2, year2) {
  dayConv = day2;
  monthConv = month2;
  yearConv = year2;
  newDate = day - dayConv;
  newMonth = month - monthConv;
  newYear = year - yearConv;
}

function mathDate() {
  if (newYear >= 1) {
    if (newMonth >= 1) {
      if (newDate >= 1) {
        console.log(newYear + " years and " + newMonth + " months and " + newDate + " days.");
        return newYear + " years and " + newMonth + " months and " + newDate + " days.";
      } else if (newDate <= 0) {
        console.log(newYear + " years and " + newMonth + " months.");
        return newYear + " years and " + newMonth + " months.";
      }
    } else if (newMonth <= 0) {
      console.log(newYear + " years and " + newDate + " days.");
      return newYear + " years and " + newDate + " days.";
    }
  } else if (newYear <= 1) {
    if (newMonth >= 1) {
      console.log(newMonth + " months and " + newDate + " days.");
      return newMonth + " months and " + newDate + " days.";
    } else if (newDate <= 0) {
      console.log(newMonth + " months.");
      return newMonth + " months.";
    } else if (newMonth <= 0) {
      console.log(newDate + " days.");
      return newDate + " days.";
    }

  }
}

age(13, 4, 2016);
mathDate();
```

Here is the answer I was able to create.